# React Native Update State With Specific Properties Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a library that accepts one type of data that looks like this:

```
const = items={[
    {label: 'USA', value: 'usa'},
    {label: 'UK', value: 'uk' },
    {label: 'France', value: 'france'}, 
]}
```

and I also have data that return to me similar data but with different properties:

```
"data": [
    {
        "ID": "USA",
        "NAME": "usa"
    },
    {
        "ID": "UK",
        "NAME": "uk"
    },
    {
        "ID": "France",
        "NAME": "france"
    },
```

I don't quite understand how to use state in this instance when I want to set it to the type of the `items` example. I have tried something like this:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
        const formattedData = apiData.map((item) => ({
            label: item.NAME,
            value: item.ID,
        }));
        setItems(formattedData);
    }
}, [apiData]);
```

my `items` return empty. what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use map function like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
        const formattedData = apiData.map((item) => ({
            label: item.NAME,
            value: item.ID,
        }));
        setItems(formattedData);
    }
}, [apiData]);
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I posted...and my `items` come out empty

Comment: you did not add map in apiData((item) in your code.

Comment: I have it in my code, just didn't paste the question properly, sorry. The problem is not in map function anyways. After I `setItems`, my items are still empty

Comment: can check the values in apiData and isloading what are you getting. because I check this code in snack expo with static data it's working fine.

Comment: can you show me the snack? I think my problem is in state declaration. the data that I get back is what I put in the question.

Comment: add `console.log(items)` after you set it and you will see its empty.

Comment: @denistepp no wonder, state hooks are async, so it could be empty immediately after calling, if your data comes exactly the way you have in your question ({ "data": [values] }), you have to preprocess it a little bit before rendering, you need to put value of the data key somewhere first, like this 
```var formattedData = data.data // <-- and then you can do rest```   you can see [here](https://snack.expo.io/@shevchenko27/restless-cashew)

Comment: I am trying to use items after I used `setItems`, so what should I do?

Comment: in both my and @JagjeetSingh examples after you do setItems, you need to refer to keys in order to get value as ```items.label items.value```

Comment: you can use like this add one more useEffect:
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(items);
}, [items]);

Comment: thank you! I use more effects to check the state of data (if it was changed) and it works.

Comment: Glad to help :)